# How to improve the sound of a bass when playing with Guitar rig (software)?

Tags: guitar, sound

Sound is very moody and unclear.

When I choose a Bass Amp from the list, even with all high frequency knobs (mid, hi, and presence) turned up in their highest position, it still sounds like underwater.

I connect my guitar straightly to a "line in" input on my motherboard (I use standard motherboard audio, no additional sound card module), without DI boxes or whatever stuff.

Here's the plot of the spectrum:
[image]

When I hit only one (lowest) 'E' string (with all amps eqs and compressors turned off, just clean signal as it goes from 'line in'):

[image]

Should I get a DI box or some additional equipment?

Added: sound sample [Sound sample](https://soundcloud.com/user545527518/tapedeck-2-may-03-12-40-22)

Comment: I'd guess the impedances are mismatched, in which case, yes, some kind of USB interface specifically designed for instruments would make a world of difference [assuming your bass sounds fine in a regular amp]

Comment: @Tetsujin, could you please look at spectrum plots I've added?

Comment: It doesn't really give me any new info, just confirms what you already said. I'd still think it's an impedance mismatch, but I'm no electronics expert, just a player.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I'm asking your diagnostic as a sound engineer :)

Comment: …but you're asking my opinion on something i've never tried - I've never just bunged a guitar straight in a lappy's headset socket. I imagine it's not going to sound very good.

Comment: @Tetsujin, wheredo you typically plug it in?

Comment: direct to a computer, something like these - http://www.sweetwater.com/c695--USB_Audio_Interfaces/low2high There are hundreds to choose from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never connect a guitar straight in to a Line-In connection.

- Line-in is around 1 Volt (in reality, audio signals are rated in dB and line levels can be in a range but 1V is a useful reference point)
- Guitars output somewhere around 150mV so you really need to put a pre-amp in the chain. A pre-amp will also sort out your impedance matching (which in your case is probably cutting a lot of your higher frequencies)

Simple answer - get a cheap pre-amp.